# Do you agree this question is "Off-Topic"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, off-topic

Do people really think that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978843/how-can-i-execute-a-mongo-foreach-or-run-my-own-js-with-monger) is off topic?  I know the asker decided that it wasn't a useful question, but I'm not sure why.

I don't feel particularly strongly about this, but I was just curious why people think this question should be put on hold.

Comment: To the OP it's the same as a typo or missing semi-colon

Comment: We'll just have to agree to disagree then. To me, this is decidedly NOT the same as a typo or a missing semi-colon. I guess I'm in the minority with that opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, closing it is entirely appropriate.  The question is based on faulty assumptions, assumptions that mean it can't meaningfully be answered, nor is it something likely to have value to future readers.

Keep in mind that it's not just closed as "offtopic".  It was closed using a custom close reason of:

> I asked this based on faulty information, the question is invalid.

*That* is what the question is closed for, and that is an appropriate reason to close a question.

Comment: The faulty information that the question is based on is exactly what I think would be useful to other users in the future.  Also, the original question (per the title) is really "how do I run JS with monger?" which @edbond gave a correct answer to.

Comment: @dbyrne It sounds like the question would still need a fair bit of rework for it to make sense to be open.  You could work to edit the question into one that fits with the one that the answer answers, possibly, although it might be better to simply ask a new question that really answers the question that you think represents the root problem here.  As it is it seems more like a reasonable answer that's tacked on a question that it doesn't quite fit with.  Keep in mind answers shouldn't be considered when determining if a question should be closed/open.

Answer (score 3):

> Do you agree this question is “Off-Topic”?

**Yes.**

First, let's look at the closing explanation :

> This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Now we can look at the scope of the help center.

From the help center :

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

OP said himself the code isn't valid so there you have it. Off-Topic.

Comment: The mongodb shell code he provided is perfectly valid: `db.collection.find().forEach(function(x) { ... })`.  Also, the code provided by @edbond which answers the question of "How can you run JS using monger?" is also valid.  The only thing which was not valid was the discrepancy between the client and server API, which is actually a useful thing to highlight for other users in my opinion.

Comment: @dbyrne IMO' the question would still need some edits to be reopenned. CLosing a question doesn't mean it gone forever. Edit it to make sure it doesn't contain bad information that could lead to bad answers and it might be reopenned. You have my vote.